# Performance of data validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, import

I have an endpoint that accepts incoming data, checks it for errors and imports into the database. Incoming data can be up to 300 000 rows. Stack is - Ruby on Rails, Postgres, Redis, Sidekiq, dry-validation. Current flow:

- load data into Redis;
- prepare/transform;
- validate and mark every row as valid/invalid;
- fetch valid rows and bulk import them.

I need an advice on how to improve the performance of the validation step here because sometimes it takes more than a day to validate a large file.

---

Some details

It basically loops through every row in the background and applies validation rules like

```
rows.each do |row|
  result = validate(row)
  set_status(row, result) # mark as valid/invalid
end
```

*Some validation rules are uniqueness checks - and they're heavy* because they check uniqueness across the whole database. Example:

```
rule(:sku, :name) do
  if Product.where(sku: values[:sku]).where.not(name: values[:name]).exists?
    # add error
  end
end
```

Needless to say, DB & logs are going mad during validation.

Another approach I tried was to `pluck` necessary fields from *all* database records, then loop through and compare every row with this array rather than make DB requests. But comparing with a huge array appeared to be even slower.

```
def existing_data
  @existing_data ||= Product.pluck(:sku, :name, ...)
end

rule(:sku, :name) do
  conflict = existing_data.find do |data|
    data[0] == values[:sku] && data[1] != values[:name]
  end
  if conflict.present?
    # add error
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get a performance improvement by doing something along the lines of your second approach, only you should try to fetch as little of the existing products as possible, preferably only the products that will be relevant to your validations. Looking only at the code provided, it seems to me like you could cut down on the amount of products that you're loading by aggregating the SKUs from the newly received `rows` and using them to filter the products table

```rb
skus = skus_from_rows(rows)
@existing_products = existing_products(skus)
rows.each do |row|
  result = validate(row)
  set_status(row, result) # mark as valid/invalid
end


def skus_from_rows(rows)
  rows.map { |row| row[:sku] }.uniq
end

def existing_products(skus)
  Product.where(sku: skus).pluck(:sku, :name, ...)
end

rule(:sku, :name) do
  conflict = @existing_products.find do |data|
    data[0] == values[:sku] && data[1] != values[:name]
  end
  if conflict.present?
    # add error
  end
end
```

Additionally, I would add an index(if not already present) to the sku column to improve the performance of the query that filters skus.